# vimperator focus firefox built in search

Tags: vimperator

Is there a keyboard shortcut to focus the built in search bar in the top right corner of Firefox?

I saw a similar question which suggested 'gi' but that's for focusing a textbox within a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the default Firefox mapping for this function called "Focus Search bar" and is [listed on the Firefox shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_search). Working on Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> focuses that box while in command mode. If that doesn't work, try prefixing it with <kbd>i</kbd> so that the keypress is ignored.

However, if your intention is to initiate a search, you can do this from the Vimperator command line (more efficiently IMO). Each search engine in Firefox has a keyword that can be used with commands `open`, `tabopen`, etc. You can see these listed in the "Search Keywords" section when you press <kbd>o</kbd> from command mode.

For example, to search Wikipedia for "superuser":

```
:open wikipedia superuser
```

This means that I've removed the search bar from my default Firefox configuration.